# feedingbottle/n”export: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, bash, bottle

I'm noob in linux, so i install feedingbottle, but then I open terminal showing this:

```
  bash: “PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/bin/feedingbottle/n”export: No such file or directory
```

The question is how to fix

ubuntu version is 14.04.1

Answer (score 2):

So you've followed this "tutorial": `http://www.n1tr0g3n.com/?p=1123`

During that it told you to:

```
printf “PATH=$%sPATH:%s/bin/feedingbottle/\n” | tee -a ~/.bashrc
```

If you look closely you'll see that it's using curly quotes instead of the straight double-quotes (eg `"`). To Bash curly quotes are just another character, they aren't special like straight quotes.

So what you've actually done is added this whole corrupted line into `~/.bashrc`. You need to fix it. Open `~/.bashrc` in Gedit, or whatever you like, find this line (it's almost certainly at the bottom) and replace it with:

```
PATH=$PATH:/bin/feedingbottle/
```

And be more careful in the future.